# How should I monitor memory usage/performance in SunOS/Solaris?

Tags: monitoring, munin, solaris-10, sunos

Last week we decided to add some SunOS (`uname -a` = `SunOS bbs-sam-belair 5.10 Generic_127128-11 i86pc i386 i86pc`) machines into our running munin instance. First off, the machines are pre-configured appliances, so, I want to avoid touching the system too much without supervision of the service provider.

But adding it to munin was fairly easy by writing a small socket-service (if anyone is interested, I put it up on github: https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/tree/master/tools/pypmmn)

Yesterday, I implemented/adapted the required plugins for our machines. And here the questions start:

First, I have not found a way to determine detailed memory usage values. I get the total memory by running `prtconf | grep Memory`, and the free memory using `vmstat`. Fiddling together a munin-plugin, gives me the following graph:

[image: SunOS memory graph]

This is pretty much uninformative. Compare this to the default plugin for linux nodes which has a lot more detail:

[image: Comparison: A Linux memory graph]

Most importantly, this shows me how much memory is actually used by applications.

**So, first question:** Is it possible to get detailed memory information on SunOS with the  *default system tools* (i.e. not using `top`)?

---

Onto the next puzzle: Seeing the graphs, I noticed activity in the "Paging in/out" graphs, *even though the memory graph still has unused memory*:

[image: Paging IN]
[image: Paging OUT]

Upon further investigation, I found out that `df` reports that `/tmp` is mounted on `swap`. Drilling around on the web, I understood that [`df` will display `swap`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs), but in fact, it's mounted as a `tmpfs`. Now I don't know if this explains the swap activity.

The default munin-plugin for solaris uses `kstat -p -c misc -m cpu_stat` to get these values. I find it already strange that this is using the `cpu_stat` module. So maybe I simply misinterpret the "paging" graphs?

**Second question:** Do the paging graphs indicate that parts of the memory are paged to disk? Or is the activity caused by file operations in `/tmp`?

Comment: Files in the `tmp` directory *are* parts of memory, unless they are paged out to disk by file operations or memory pressure. That's how `tmpfs` works.

Comment: Also, your "even though the memory graph still has unused memory" is based on a misunderstanding. The only reason that memory is free is because the system needs it to be free. (For example, to handle network and disk interrupts.) If memory usage goes up such that the system didn't have enough free memory, it would have to squeeze the cache or page out to ensure it had enough free memory. (If you added another 8GB to the machine, you'd have 8GB more memory used and the same memory free. So adding memory would make the system faster. Not just leave more free memory doing nothing.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Hmmm... so the "memory usage" graph is essentially useless without the detailed information. Thanks for explaining this!

Comment: That's correct. It's like looking at a bank account balance without seeing deposits and withdrawals. The family could be living large or starving and have $500 in the bank either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***first question: Is it possible to get detailed memory information on SunOS with the default system tools (i.e. not using top)?***

It is definitely possible to get detailed memory statistics and more with Solaris standard tools (SunOS is only the kernel name nowadays). In addition to the already mentioned `echo ::memstat | mdb -k`, you can have memory statistics per process and per user with `prstat -a` and per zone with `prstat -Z`.

The kernel is also providing numerous statistics through the kstat interface (munin is using them).

For example, if you want to display the total RAM, the part of it used by the kernel, by the ZFS cache (part of kernel used memory), and the free memory, you can run this command:

```
kstat -T d -p :::physmem :::pp_kernel zfs:::size :::pagesfree 1 3
```

If you are looking to virtual memory usage, use the `swap -s` command.

***Second question: Do the paging graphs indicate that parts of the memory are paged to disk? Or is the activity caused by file operations in /tmp?***

None of the above. Having such activity doesn't necessarily means a lack of RAM and page thrashing. On the opposite, your graph shows the `sr` value staying at 0. That means the page scanner has no activity and thus that you have enough RAM installed. The paging activity is simply due to memory mapped files being read and written. Nothing to worry about. The files being on /tmp are only present in RAM (in your case), so no paging occur when accessing them.

Beware that Solaris uses the swap term to either name the part of disk used to store memory pages that are paged out from RAM or to name the whole virtual memory space, i.e. the swap area plus the part of RAM that is not locked there.

Comment: I tried to write a script based on `mdb`. But for some reason, when run through munin, I don't get any values. If I run it manually, it works. Any ideas?

Comment: nevermind: it works. I needed to restart the munin node for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Not as detailed as your Linux example but you could use the **::memstat** macro in **mdb**:

```
# echo ::memstat | mdb -k
Page Summary                Pages                MB  %Tot
------------     ----------------  ----------------  ----
Kernel                     178001              1390   69%
Anon                        52748               412   21%
Exec and libs                1905                14    1%
Page cache                  16115               125    6%
Free (cachelist)             6654                51    3%
Free (freelist)              1452                11    1%

Total                      256875              2006
Physical                   255662              1997
```

**Kernel**: memory used for non-pageable kernel allocations

**Anon**: anonymous memory (process heaps, stack, share memory mappings, etc. etc.)

**Exec and libs**: memory used for mapped files like executables and libraries

**Page cache**: amount of unmapped page cache including data stored in /tmp

**Free (cachelist)**: amount of page cache on free list, majority used by file system caches

**Free (freelist)**: amount of memory that is actually really free

The two books about Solaris Internals (Solaris Internals, 2nd Edition and Solaris Performance and Tools) by McDougall and Mauro are extremely helpful to understand Solaris and how to observe it.

Comment: Hmmm... this was a hard one to accept... Sorry for not accepting yours. But @jlliagre answered both parts. Even though, your part about the memory was more helpful as it includes an example, and actually explaining the observed values... But unfortunately I can only accept one :( At least, have an upvote.